# QGraphicsScene::clear() clearing scene but not the view

Tags: qt, debugging, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I use a custom class (`Configuration`) derived from `QGraphicsItem` and I add its objects to a `QGraphicsScene`, which is then displayed in a `QGraphicsView`. Usual stuff. What Im doing exactly is drawing a tree, in multiple steps, one level a step, each node beeing my custom `QGraphicsItem`.

[image]

Here a screenshot. The tree happens to be sequential in the simple case.

I first draw the root node. The signal that triggers that is fired after the user entered a string.

```
void MainWindow::drawRootSlot(ConfigTreeBuilder & builder)//this is a slot
{
    c_scene->clear();  //the clear cause headache. i'll expain

    Configuration* conf = new Configuration(builder.getNodesX(), builder.getNodesY(),builder.getNodesConfig());
//code
    c_scene->addItem(conf);
//code
}
```

Each subsequent `Configuration` is draw inside another slot.

```
void MainWindow::configTreeSlot(ConfigTreeBuilder & builder)    //SLOT!!!
{
    while(builder.chooseNextNode()) {

        Configuration* conf = new Configuration(builder.getNodesX(), builder.getNodesY(), builder.getNodesConfig());

       //code, while loop    
            QGraphicsLineItem *edge = c_scene->addLine(QLineF(*(parentsPoint), conf->getLeftOrigin()));
            edge->setZValue(-1); //below the Configuration item


        c_scene->addItem(conf);
    }

}
```

All works fine when done for the first time. When I  enter a new string, resetting the tree, dark magic happens. What I expected to it do is: call `drawRootSlot()`,  deleting the whole tree (`c_scene->clear()`), draw a new root node. And, if I put a debugger breakpoint inside `drawRootSlot()` this is exactly what happens! But when I run it (without breakpoints), what I get is this:

[image]

The previous tree got mangled, but not deleted. The scene gets indeed cleared of its items (printed that) but the view  does not reflect that. But again, when I put a breakpoint inside `drawRootSlot()` thhe view and the scene are in sync.

I tried to delete the scene object, and instaciate a new one instead of calling `c_scene->clear()`, to guarantee it empty. Then the changes are reflected on the view (the first time drawing always works).

So, I have no idea what to deduce from these symptoms. It works as expected with a breakpoint or with a freshh `QGraphicsScene` object. It does not when just using `c_scene->clear()`. One couldsay I just messed up the parent-object/child-object relation, but `clear()` *does* remove items from the view... I tried calling it right after `c_scene->addItem()`.

What is this sorrcery? One that makes me believe I'm not actually stupid?

**EDIT:** Whats interesting and may be a hint to the real problem, is that when `c_scene->clear()` is called, the edges of the tree, which are normal `QGraphicsLineItem`s, are indeed deleted in all cases (breakpoint or not). Something to do with them *not* beeing custom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, calling `QGraphicsView::viewport().update()` after `QGraphicsScene::clear()` solved my problems.

But does anyone have an explanaition to the behavior described above?

**EDIT**: Upon doing doing something else I stumbled upon the actual core of the problem: I messed up the `boundingRect()` of my GraphicItems, so it was below the visble item, touching only its lower edge (which got deleted, as seen on the screenshot). So now no calls to any `update()` methods are neccesary.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you call this [fitInView()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#fitInView) for the graphicsview it cleans up the view from any artifacts that remain from a previous scene.

Answer (score -1):

You can clear both scene and Graphics View

```
scene->clear();
ui->graphicsView->items().clear();
```

graphicsView = name of your graphics view

This code will delete both scene and graphics view